# Can I let swagger-codegen ignore some method parameters

Tags: swagger-codegen, method-signature, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

I use `swagger-codegen` in my maven build to generate the Java interfaces for my REST layer. This works very well. However, there are a couple of parameters that I would like to exclude from the generated method's argument list.

## Question

Is it possible to let swagger-codegen exclude certain parameters (e.g., by name)?

> Instead of
>
> - `public Response getFromEndpoint(String userToken, String xRequestId, String foo)`
>
> I would like to get
>
> - `public Response getFromEndpoint(String foo)`

I do want those parameters to remain in the documentation

## Why

I will use the omitted headers in a filter, but subsequently they have become irrelevant in the generated method so I don't want them there.
Being able to exclude them also has the benefit that I don't have to fix every method signature in my implementation after I add a new security related parameter.

---

## My setup

#### pom.xml

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
```

#### swagger.yaml

```
paths:
  /endpoint
    get:
      tags:
        - example
      operationId: getFromEndpoint
      parameters:
        - name: user-token
          in: header
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
        - name: X-request-id
          in: header
          required: false
          schema:
            type: string
        - name: foo
          in: header
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: sample response
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: string
```

Comment: [This](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/7957) might be a feature that you need. It was started from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43044439/swagger-codegen-header-parameter-for-java-rest-client) thread.